# railstutorial.org chapter 10 Not clear why activation experiment should work as described

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

Listing 10.16 shows how to use the test mailers:

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def account_activation
    user = User.first
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    UserMailer.account_activation(user)
  end
end
```

and figure 10.5 shows that by going to the activation link supplied by the test mailer, the account was successfully activated.

I understand why this should work in production. But here, UserMailerPreview class generates a new token which is then compared to the activation_token digest stored in the database. This digest was generated when the user object was created, as described in section 10.3 of the tutorial.

```
before_create :create_activation_digest
```

As I understand it, the digest created from the new token in UserMailerPreview should not match the digest in the database, yet figure 10.5 suggests otherwise. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> digest created from the new token in UserMailerPreview should not match the digest in the database

You're right, but [Listing 11.18](https://www.learnenough.com/ruby-on-rails-6th-edition-tutorial/account_activation#code-account_activation_preview) sets up the *preview* seen in [Figure 11.3](https://www.learnenough.com/ruby-on-rails-6th-edition-tutorial/account_activation#fig-account_activation_html_preview), and has nothing to do with the live (development) version seen in [Figure 11.6](https://www.learnenough.com/ruby-on-rails-6th-edition-tutorial/account_activation#fig-activated_user).

Comment: Can you reactivate the links, please?

Comment: @Alexs Done. Bear in mind that, although the links now go to the right places, they are still behind a paywall, so they will be accessible only to purchasers of the book or subscribers to the course. (A scholarship program is available in case cost is a factor: https://www.learnenough.com/scholarship)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial suggests using the link form section 10.23 (the server log), NOT the link generated as a result of the actions of UserMailerPreview.